# Python call to Intersystems Cache class to get global sizes produces results and a failure code

Tags: python, caching

I am writing a Python tool to access an Intersystems Cache database (2018.1.x). I am using this import:

```
import intersys2.pythonbind3 as pyb
```

connectivity:

```
self.conn   = pyb.connection()
self.conn.connect_now(f'{url}[{port}]:%SYS', userName, password,None)

# Create objects used to access cache/iris
self.db     = pyb.database(self.conn)
```

to get the global size:

```
# Clear byRef variables
allocated = 0
used      = 0
chkFlg    = False
nxGlobal  = "STRELPERF"
                
# Set args to pass by reference
list = [db,nxGlobal,allocated,used,chkFlg]

# exec the class method to get the global size
res = self.db.run_class_method("%Library.GlobalEdit", <db>,"GetGlobalSize")
```

But when I call the method:

```
status = self.genClassMethod('%SYSTEM.Status','IsError',[res])
```

Status always comes back as 1. But, for databases with the global the allocated and used sizes are returned with correct values even though a failure status is being returned. For cases where the status is failure but correct values are returned, the error text is `(no error description)`

How can this method produce valid results and return a failure code? What am I missing?